# MVVM and dynamic generation of controls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

i've written a tool that generates sql queries using GUI, i want to rewrite the tool using MVVM and WPF, every sql column type has a different control as you can see in the following image

[image]

i add a column filter control based on the sql column type, and i generate the controls using code, just like i used to do in windows forms.

1. in MVVM i've read that the view is writtien enteirly using XAML,
   does MVVM suite such application where i have to add different user
   controls dynamically to a stack panel?
2. The controls won't exist in the view unless some column is double clicked, that means the control won't be available in the xaml and won't be hidden or collapsed.
3. is there any way that i can avoid the bindings in the code behind?
4. should i create a user control for each column type?
5. in general what is the best approach to devlop such application with complex and dynamic ui using mvvm?

Comment: XAML is not MVVM. And WPF != MVVM. WPF is good friend of MVVM an XAML is just UI markup. 
XAML-view isn't XAML only - it has glued class (so called Code-Behind), but you shouldn't use it for main logic,  use it as less as possible.
Of course, you can implement controls generation in code-behind, but this is **ABSOLUTELY NOT A MVVM** approach.

Comment: @user1590636 your generated GUI looks really nice and simple

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Guess I know how to achieve that, but it is very complex stuff. First you should comprehend MVVM basic concepts.
Main ViewModel should be a class with `ObservableCollection` of ViewModels, each of them represents a column with its data and properties.

```
interface IViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged,IDisposable
{
}

interface IColumnViewModel : IViewModel
{
}

class ViewModelBase : IViewModel
{
    // ... MVVM basics, PropertyChanged etc. ...
}

class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    ObservableCollection<IColumnViewModel> Columns {get; set}
}
```

In View I suppose something like `ItemsControl` with `ItemTemplate`, that should embed `ContentControl` with `DataTemplate`, that shall be automatically selected by WPF according to binded `DataContext` of list item. `StackPanel` itself is not suitable for that, but it can be invoked as `ItemsPanelTemplate`

```
<Window
    xmlns:v="clr-namespace:WpfApplication.Views"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WpfApplication.ViewModels">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type TypeName=vm:TextColumnViewModel}">
            <v:TextColumnView/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <ItemsControl
        ItemsSource="{Binding Columns}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Window>
```

So, you should build View/ViewModel pair for every column type.

*Hope, my example will help. Good luck with your girlfriend and MVVM :)*

Answer (score 3):

If I've understood your scenario correctly :
You can use Data Templates & Items Templates
For example I've written an application which loads Data into Collection and then shows each item of that collection in a Wrap Panel [ Or stack panel ] based on defined data template.
And Wrap penel items are in sync by the collection itself within two way binding
You should consider using Observable Collections to achieve this goal
Then you can fill the collection and see the results on a view
I hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

To write something like this in MVVM, you would have one view that is say, your content area.  That view would have a view model, one of the properties of that view model would be a view, or several properties of that view model would be a view.  It takes a bit to wrap your head around at times, but if you use Inversion of Control and Dependency Injection properly a view of views is very manageable in an MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your view isn't written entirely in XAML - you generate controls in C#.

I don't think you'll gain something from rewriting this and fitting it into an MVVM mold. Just keep the code as it is now and enjoy.

Comment: problem is my girlfriend won't marry me if i don't use MVVM, if you were you to write somthing like that with MVVM, could give me a general idea on how you would do it?

Comment: @zmbq he doesn't need to create bindings in code he just has to use a hole bunch of DataTemplates which should be able to display his stuff in a generic way