# Generate controls Dynamically in View for MVVM windows 8

Tags: c#, mvvm

I am working on a Windows 8 Store application using MVVM.
The Requirement for me is to create a dynamic survey page where depending upon the question type (Multiple choice, single choice, Text box or rating buttons) i have to display the answers to the user with the value.

Question i have is:

How to display the dynamic control in to the view.
Should i create the dynamic controls in the View Model cs file or the Cs file of View.

Please provide me with some suggestions.

Thanks for Reading

Regards

Biju

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) For example i use ViewModel like this:

```
public enum AnswerType {OneAnswer, MultipleAnswers}

public class QuestionViewModel : ViewModel
{
    public AnswerType type;
    public string[] Answers;
}
```

2) View responsibility - representing data from ViewModel:
My empty view in XAML:

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    x:Class="AnswerView.cs"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:sdkControlTiltEffect"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="173" d:DesignWidth="173">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I inject my ViewModel to View as constructor parameter. You cfn use DataContext instead.
My dynamic view background class:

```
public class AnswerView : UserControl
{
    public AnswerView(QuestionViewModel q)
    {
        switch(q.Type)
        {
            case AnswerType.OneAnswer:
            //Put log for jne answer view generation
            break;
            case AnswerType.MultipleAnswers:
            //Put logic for multiple answers View generation
            break;
            default:
        }

    }
}
```

You should never create view elements in ViewModel. It ruins MVVM in fundamentals. ViewModel must be independent from View.

I think it should be helpfull:
[MVVM and dynamic generation of controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18560776/mvvm-and-dynamic-geneation-of-controls)

Comment: Thanks Vyacheslav.

Let me try this and let you know :)

Comment: I am trying this but i am getting stuck at one point.

For example if the Answer type is Multiple choices i should create check box and if it is multiple options with one selection then i have to use the radio box. 

So where do i create those controls?

Comment: You should create all controls in:
`//Put logic for multiple answers View generation`

Code looks like this:
`foreach(var answer in q.Answers)
{
  var checkBox = GetCheckboxForAanswer(answer);
  LayoutRoot.Childrens.Add(checkBox);
}`

Sample GetCheckboxForAanswerimplementation:
`CheckBox GetCheckboxForAanswer(string answer)
{
  return new CheckBox(){Content = answer};
}`

Comment: are you trying to say that this code should be part of the View?

Comment: Yes. I tryed to say it)

Comment: It is working and thanks :) But i have one more scenario which i want to clarify with you. Here there might be more than 5 questions and i have to click on next button to show the next question in the same page. During that scenario what will happen as the button firing command is available in the View Model and not in the view?

Comment: If you click button in view, method like `nextBtnClick` will call in ViewModel. In that method you can implement logic for answer storing and ViewModel updating for new question. After ViewModel updating changes will show in the View.